# Installing python modules inside Cygwin

Tags: python, python-3.x, cygwin, pywin32

I have problem when I install python modules using Cygwin on windows. First, I install anaconda. Secondly, I installed Cygwin. if I install any modules using normal windows command promote, the library is installed in the anaconda directory and works perfectly. I'm trying to install pywin32 inside the Cygwin itself. Every time I got this error:

$ pip install pywin32
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32
I can install this library easily via anaconda, but I got the above error when I tried to install it inside the Cygwin. It seems that there are some python modules can be installed smoothly inside the Cygwin while others are not. any suggestions

Comment: The `pywin32` package is not available for Cygwin, as it contains content that is specific to the Windows environment. Many other package are available through Cygwin setup, and most pure python modules can be installed with `pip`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do:

- Close all Cygwin processes.
- Execute the Cygwin setup app.
- Leave all automatic updates selected.
- Search for any desired but uninstalled packages under "Full", and select them.
- Complete the setup.
- Open a cygwin terminal.
- Execute `python -V` or `python2 -V` to confirm the version. Use python or python2 as required below.
- Execute `python -m pip …` where `…` is a pip command.
- Execute `python -m pip list` to see what packages are installed.
- Execute `python -m pip install -U pylint`, for example.

There are a couple of restrictions:

- Always install the package from Cygwin setup, if it is available, because that package will have Cygwin specific changes.
- Do not install or update a package that can be installed by Cygwin setup using pip, as the PyPi package may not include Cygwin specific changes, and will not have the correct binary content for Cygwin.